# TList of Record types leaking memory

Tags: delphi, record, tlist

Code that looks approximately like the following leaks memory for each string instance in each TMyRecord created.  I presume I must visit each record and free it somehow -- can that be done without nilling each individual string?

```
function TMyForm.RecordFromThing(thing): TMyRecord;
begin
   result.StringVal1 = thing.SomeProperty;
   result.StringVal2 = thing.SomeOtherProperty;
end;

function TMyForm.RecordsFromItems: TList<TMyRecord>;
begin
   result := TList<TMyRecord>.Create;
   for thing in things do
   begin
     result.Add(RecordFromThing(thing));
   end;
end;

procedure TMyForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var Items: TList<TMyRecord;
begin

  Items := RecordsFromItems;
  try
    //Stuff
  finally
    // What goes here to free those records?
    Items.Clear;
    Items.Free;
  end

end;
```

As per David's request, here is actual code cut-and-pasted from my application.  If I run Button1Click then FastMM reports string memory leaks.

```
  type TPremiumPaymentInstruction = record
    SupplierID: string;
    FirstName: string;
    LastName: string;
    PolicyNo: string;
    CarrierName: string;
    PayAmount: string;
    DueDate: string;
    PayMethod: string;
    Comments: string;
    Payee: string;
    Address: string;
    Address2: string;
    City: string;
    State: string;
    Zip: string;
    InRe: string;
    BankName: string;
    BankABA: string;
    AccountName: string;
    AccountNo: string;
    CreditTo: string;
  end;

function TPremiumPaymentManager.RecordFromItem(Item: TListItem): TPremiumPaymentInstruction;
var PolicyID: integer;
    Instructions: TDataSet;

    function FormatNote(PolicyNo, First, Last: string): string;
    begin
      result := 'Policy# ' + PolicyNo + '; Insured Name: ' + Last + ' ' + First;
    end;

begin

  FillChar(result, SizeOf(result), 0);

  result.SupplierID  := Item.Caption;
  result.FirstName   := Item.SubItems[INSURED_FIRST_NAME_COLUMN];
  result.LastName    := Item.SubItems[INSURED_LAST_NAME_COLUMN];
  result.PolicyNo    := Item.SubItems[POLICY_NUMBER_COLUMN];
  result.CarrierName := Item.SubItems[CARRIER_NAME_COLUMN];
  result.PayAmount   := Item.SubItems[ACTUAL_COLUMN];
  result.DueDate     := Item.SubItems[DATE_DUE_COLUMN];
  result.PayMethod   := Item.SubItems[PAYMENT_METHOD_COLUMN];

  PolicyID := GetSingleValue('SELECT PolicyID FROM PremiumsDue WHERE PremiumID = :PremiumID;', [(Item as TAdvListItem).KeyValue], 0);
  Instructions := GetDS('SELECT I.* FROM Policies P INNER JOIN CarrierPaymentInstructions I ON P.CarrierID = I.CarrierID AND P.PaymentInstruction = I.InstructionDescription WHERE P.PolicyID = ?;', [PolicyID]);

  try

    Instructions.Open;
    Instructions.First;

    if result.PayMethod = 'Check' then
      begin
        result.Comments := Item.SubItems[PAYMENT_NOTE_COLUMN];
        result.Payee    := Instructions.FieldByName('PayTo').AsString;
        result.Address  := Instructions.FieldByName('Address1').AsString;
        result.Address2 := Instructions.FieldByName('Address2').AsString;
        result.City     := Instructions.FieldByName('City').AsString;
        result.State    := Instructions.FieldByName('State').AsString;
        result.Zip      := Instructions.FieldByName('ZipCode').AsString;
        result.InRe     := FormatNote(result.PolicyNo, result.FirstName, result.LastName);
      end
    else
      begin
        result.BankName    := Instructions.FieldByName('PayTo').AsString;
        result.BankABA     := Instructions.FieldByName('ABANumber').AsString;
        result.Address2    := Instructions.FieldByName('Address2').AsString;
        result.AccountName := Instructions.FieldByName('AccountName').AsString;
        result.AccountNo   := Instructions.FieldByName('AccountNumber').AsString;
        result.CreditTo    := FormatNote(result.PolicyNo, result.FirstName, result.LastName);
      end;

  finally

    Instructions.Free;

  end;

end;

function TPremiumPaymentManager.RecordsFromItems: TList<TPremiumPaymentInstruction>;
var item: TListItem;
begin

  result := TList<TPremiumPaymentInstruction>.Create;

  for item in lvPremiums.Items do
  begin
    if (not (Item as TAdvListItem).Strikeout) and (Item.SubItems[ACTUAL_COLUMN] <> '')  then
      result.Add( RecordFromItem(item) );
  end;

end;

procedure TPremiumPaymentManager.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var Items: TList<TPremiumPaymentInstruction>;
begin

  Items := RecordsFromItems;
  Items.Clear;
  Items.Free;

end;
```

Comment: Cut-and-paste from my failing code has been added to the question.

Comment: Use `result := Default(TPremiumPaymentInstruction)` to initialize your record.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are managed types. The compiler takes charge of their allocation and deallocation. The compiler writes code that maintains reference counts to the string data. When the reference count goes to zero, the memory is deallocated.

As such, you don't need to deallocate strings or indeed perform any explicit management. Any attempt to do so will likely clash with that performed by the compiler. For instance, if you perform raw memory access on a string variable, saw with a call to `FillChar`, then the reference counting will be bypassed.

The code in your question, beyond being incomplete and in parts not compiling, is essentially fine. When you are done with your `TList<TMyRecord>` simply free it. The compiler will generate code to release all references. No need even to clear it.

```
List := TList<TMyRecord>.Create;
try
  List.Add(...);
  // etc. 
finally
  List.Free;
end;
```

That's all you need.

Since the code in you question is essentially the same as this, I conclude that the cause of your leak is elsewhere.

---

What do you know, your edit contains that tell-tale call to `FillChar`. Replace that with

```
Result := Default(TPremiumPaymentInstruction);
```

You do always need to initialize return values. Even return values that are managed types which often are initialized. But not when the call is made inside a for loop in the manner of yours. Go figure. Anyway, always initialize return values. And `Default(T)` is your friend.

Comment: I cut-and-pasted the actual code into the question.  Please note that I *am* using FillChar on each record as without that initialization I was getting string pointers apparently repeated from record to record.

Comment: Thanks, working now.  I have a faint glimmer of why this failed, but only faint.  Will look at it again later to see if I can figure out why. . .

Comment: It failed because you bypassed reference counting by doing a raw memory write. Nothing actually released the references to the strings since you wrote over the references. Behind the compiler's back. FillChar is not your friend here, not with managed types.

Comment: Is it the FillChar leak, or the result var already initialized that is stumping you?

Comment: Primarily why using FillChar means that the later strong assignment cannot be freed by the compiler, but also why the strings in the record must be manually initialized when (I believe) that's not generally true of strings. And why, in that case, the compiler does not produce an "X may not have been initialized" type message.

Comment: `Result` contains the content of the previous call, when the caller is in that for loop. All should be clear from there. Compiler doesn't warn about managed types being initialized. Golden rule, always initialize all variables.

Comment: Aha!  I assumed that the new Record having the same string values as the last one (which surprised me to begin with) was an artifact of memory management (not a deliberate language construct) and it never struck me that that constituted an additional reference to the strings in the old Record.  Also, despite many years of on-and-off Delphi (and Turbo Pascal before that) I'm embarrassed to say I never ran into `Default()` before.

Comment: `Default(T)` is new, to support generics. Not well documented, if documented at all. Grr. So not surprising you've not seen it. `Result` is actually a `var` parameter technically. Implicit of course. Implemented that way for types that don't fit in registers or are managed. So, being a `var` parameter, they may have a value on entry. Compiler thinks it's a `var` and so neglects to warn you. The entire handling of function return values in Delphi is, in my opinion, a total screw up.